# Best way to have a defined argument follow an argument with default value in ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6

In ES6 with default value syntax for function parameters, what's the best way to define the 2nd argument while using the default value for the 1st one in a function call?

```
function test(arg1 = 2, arg2 = 3) {
    return arg1 + arg2;
}

test() // returns 5;
test(undefined, 2) // returns 4; is this the most concise way?
```

Also, does the second method call work according to the standard? I only tested it with my cross-compiler which just inserts a statement setting the arguments value if it's equal to `undefined`; not sure if in actual ES6 engines it looks as the way the function was actually called.

Comment: If you don't want to simulate named arguments with an object instead, then yes, that's the shortest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the best way to define the 2nd argument while using the default value for the 1st one in a function call?

Yes, [passing `undefined` is the correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42208133/1048572).

> Is this working according to the standard? Not sure if it actually looks at the way the function was called.

No, `undefined` is equivalent to a parameter not passed in the arguments list - in both directions. If you explicitly pass `undefined`, the default initialiser will be run just as if you had passed nothing. If you don't pass anything, all parameters (without defaults) will be assigned `undefined` just as if you had passed it explictly.
The only way to distinguish them would be using `arguments.length`.

> Is this the most concise way?

Yes. Elisions (like in the array `[,,,]`) are syntactically invalid in function calls. You could shorten `undefined` to `void 0`, but that's not really idiomatic (only a minifier would do this).